# Python QT (PySide) How to pass external variable to the class

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am fairly new to Python QT and the object orientated game. Here is the situation:

I have an array of dictionaries, I need to output some of these keys and values into the GUI. I have to know how many keys/values so of course that means I need to count them. How do I pass the "dic" so that the "qCount" function (see code below) can get my number of keys so I can populate the correct number of fields in the GUI. (Its a list of questions that will take an answer that will get read back in)

I would think something like "class output_GUI(QtGui.QWidget, arrayofdics)" would be what I would do, but that seems more like something for a function declaration not that of a class. I'm sure there is also something I need to pass to the instance of the class but I am not very knowledgeable on the subject.

Any advice well appreciated,

Thank you,

Pablo

```
class output_GUI(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
            super(output_GUI, self).__init__()
            self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
         #populate fields with obtained keys
         #some code.....


    def qCount(dic):
            for n, ques in enumerate(d['Question'] for d in dic):
                    #get number of questions etc...
def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = output_GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's unclear where the dictionary is coming from. Depending on that you need to pass it in one way or the other. You basically do not give enough information to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Umm.. I am not sure if I totally understand you question or not. It seems your question is more about the object orientated programming. The following code maybe is what your need:

```
class output_GUI(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(output_GUI, self).__init__()
            self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #populate fields with obtained keys
        #some code.....
        self.your_variable = 1
        self.your_dic = {'1': 'How are you?', '2': 'Where are you going?'}

    def print_your_variable_for_fun(self):
        print self.your_variable  # output->1
        self.your_variable = 2
        print self.your_variable  # output->2
        self.your_variable = 1

    def qCount(self):
        for n, ques in enumerate(self.your_dic.values()):
            #get number of questions etc...
            print n, ques

    def qAdding(self, newQuestion):
        # adding question into your question dictionary
        self.your_dic[str(len(self.your_dic)+1)] = str(newQuestion)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = output_GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In you output_GUI class, each of your member function can be established by passing 'self' (the class itself) as function argument. So that its member function can manipulate its (output_GUI_class) properties.